# TypeScript with VSC: Intellisense not recognizing inherited methods from super class

Tags: typescript, intellisense

I've been developing a monorepo project and in one of my packages I have an abstract class to deal with Firestore CRUD:

```js
export abstract class FirestoreOperator<E> implements DataOperator<E> {
    abstract getCollection(): CollectionReference<E>

    async delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
        await this.getCollection().doc(id).delete()
    }

    async update(id: string, data: E): Promise<void> {
        await this.getCollection().doc(id).set({...data}, {merge: true})
    }
    
    async save(data: E, id: string = uuid()): Promise<void> {
        await this.getCollection().doc(id).set(data);
    }

    async get(id: string): Promise<E | undefined> {
        const docSnapshot =  await this.getCollection().doc(id).get()
        return await docSnapshot.data()
    }
}
```

And then I implemented it:

```js
export class FirestoreMetaOperator extends FirestoreOperator<Meta> {
    private readonly metaId: string
    
    constructor(metaId: string) {
        super()
        metaId = metaId
    }

    getCollection(): CollectionReference<Meta> {
        return getFirestore()
            .collection(firestorePath.meta(metaId))
            .withConverter(firestoreMetaConverter)
    }
}
```

My problem started after I started generating declaration maps with tsc. Before it, I was using a bundler to generate the .d.ts and it worked well. Now, whenever I import the implementation  in another package in my monorepo, it seems that the IntelliSense can't identify the super class methods.

What is happening?